# how to configure vsftp deny plain ftp connection

Tags: linux, vsftpd

I have configure FTPS using vsftp, FTP is working perfectly fine, how do I deny the incoming connection for plain FTP and only allow FTPS connection.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

Need to include this 2 lines configuration

```
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
```